# jQuery AJAX with an interval

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, setinterval

I have a question about an AJAX call within an interval. And why it doesn't work, or work the way it works.

I have this code (this one doesn't work)

```
setInterval($.ajax({
  //Place code here
}), 2000);
```

but then I make it this way

```
setInterval(function() {
  $.ajax({
    //Do ajax stuff here
  });
}, 2000);
```

Now it works, but to me this looks like I only make an extra anonymous function.

Comment: You need to provide a function to be executed on each interval. `$.ajax` does not return a function, hence it does not work.

Comment: Great question @Rob! Hopefully my edits will help you understand the correct usage of markdown :) There is a [meta post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox) that is a dedicated sandbox to play with the post format - perhaps that will also help you get used to markdown.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`setInterval` requires a function or executable code in string format.

The first call will work when put within a string.

```
setInterval('$.ajax({ //Place code here })', 2000);
```

Using this syntax is discouraged for the same reasons as using `eval`.

`setInterval` can also take an optional list of params.
You can take advantage of this fact and use something like this:

```
setInterval($.ajax/*a reference to the ajax function*/,
 2000, {url: 'someurl', success: onSuccess, error: onError}/*args passed to $.ajax*/
);
```

Note that this wouldn't work for object methods that use `this` to determine the context, as the value of `this` will be bound to `window`. That is, the following wouldn't work:

```
setTimeout($('h1').css, 1000, {'color': 'red'});
```

Comment: Can you please change the code sample so that it doesn't use `eval`? I'm ok with keeping the disclaimer.

Comment: @FritsvanCampen, but bro, that is the only example code in my post.

Comment: I think I like this way more than the way of using a anomynous function :)

Comment: This is new to me.  Excellent.

Answer (score 3):

`setInterval` requires a function as first argument [(Reference)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.setInterval) and that's why `setInterval($.ajax({ //Place code here }), 2000);` does not work, because `$.ajax` function returns a `jQuery XMLHttpRequest object` [(Reference)](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

`setInterval(function() { $.ajax({ //Do ajax stuff here }); }, 2000);` creates indeed an anonymous function but is necessary unless you quote your code to make it a `string`.